# How to pass the arguments to the request from the form template

Tags: http, flask, request, wtforms

I'd like to pass additional argument `next` (it should be endpoint) to the request when submitting the form. I've tried:
`<form method="post" action="" next="/apply">` but it doesn't work.
Later when receiving the form I just need to read it from `request.args`. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden form field.

```
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/apply">
    <!-- the rest of your form code -->
```

In your Flask function:

```
    next = request.form.get('next')
```